# Axios JS get Response returns undefinied on a URL that appears to be working

Tags: next.js, axios, get, undefined

I am trying to return a JSON from github api in Next.JS using axios.get

```js
import axios from "axios";

const getLatestRepos = async (data, token) => {
  try {
    const username = data.githubUsername;

    if (token) {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:${username}+sort:author-date-asc`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `token ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      let repos = res.data.items;
      let latestThreeRepos = repos.splice(0, 3);
 
      return latestThreeRepos;
    } else {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:${username}+sort:author-date-asc`
      );
      let repos = res.data.items;
      let latestThreeRepos = repos.splice((Math.random() * repos.length -3), 3);
      return latestThreeRepos;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

export default getLatestRepos;
```

My console log out tosses the following:

```
PS D:\Dev\personal_site\nextres> npm install

up to date, audited 917 packages in 3s

175 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

13 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 7 critical)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\Dev\personal_site\nextres> npm run dev

> nextres@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 134 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 102 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- warn You are using an experimental edge runtime, the API might change.
- wait compiling / (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 570 ms (509 modules)
undefined
[TypeError: adapter is not a function]
[Error: Error serializing `.repositories` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.]
- wait compiling /favicon.ico/route (client and server)...
- event compiled successfully in 49 ms (105 modules)
```

I have tried using fetch instead of axios with similar results. The expectation is to return my repo from github, and grab a random selection of 3. This code was functioning just yesterday as expected but now its off which leads me to believe it some kind of package or configuration issue.I have tried to force install even roll back to npm 6

```
PS D:\Dev\personal_site\nextres> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter@0.3.1
npm ERR! Found: axios@0.21.4
npm ERR! node_modules/axios
npm ERR!   axios@"^0.21.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer axios@">=0.26.0" from @vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter@0.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter
npm ERR!   @vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter@"^0.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: axios@1.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/axios
npm ERR!   peer axios@">=0.26.0" from @vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter@0.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter
npm ERR!     @vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter@"^0.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\thela\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-16T01_55_01_019Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\thela\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-16T01_55_01_019Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried force and legacy-peer-deps to no avail. I even blew away my node_modules and package-lock.json